# Stuck on logo, cannot install

Tags: boot, grub2, 15.04, kubuntu

I have been trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop for some time. I always get stuck on the logo after choosing install in grub2. I can't enter the live environment either. I use a live USB, and an ISO that I checked. The laptop is an Asus f553ma. I tried editing the start options and removed splash and quiet to get a command line. I get stuck on "systemd-journal-flush.service". I get the same result with Ubuntu 15.04, as I do with kubuntu 15.04. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble. You'll need to change the bios settings. First of all, disable secure and fast boot options (enable crm). Change the SATA config to IDE and (for any reason.. do not ask me why) I had to set the windows mode to windows 7 in bios.
Once you did the changes the installer can get finished (I used a live usb stick created in ubuntu).
After that I still needed to boot windows, adding an entry for Grub2 using [EasyBSD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). Now you can reboot and use Grub to choose the Ubuntu/Linux Distibutions.